# Drawing arrow with shape class

Tags: java, javafx, shapes

I am hardly trying to make a dynamic arrow with Shape class on javafx that on each mouse click, changes orientation (the orientation degree is given randomly between 0 and 360).
So I have 2 issues :

1. I could not draw a total arrow, only the head, not the line.
2. I don't know how to change its orientation to make it point in a different degree each time.

Here's a piece of what I did, it's making me a head of an arrow without a line and static (not moving) : 
When I add a Line shape, it's considering it like 2 different shapes, not a single arrow.

Thanks for help.

```
public StrengthItem (final Projection projection, final int strengthValue, final int speedValue) {
    super();
    final double halfTriangleEdge = 5.0;
    double windOrientation = 0;

    arrowOrientation = getArrowOrientation();

    final Polyline arrow = new Polyline();
    arrow.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] { 0.0, -halfTriangleEdge, -halfTriangleEdge, halfTriangleEdge, halfTriangleEdge, halfTriangleEdge, 0.0, -halfTriangleEdge });
    arrow.setStrokeWidth(1.0);
    arrow.setLayoutY(7);
    arrow.setLayoutX(51);

    getChildren().add(arrow);

}

private double getArrowOrientation() {

    double pArrowOrientation = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    pWindOrientation = r.nextInt(360);

    return pWindOrientation;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the same input, but some  for creating/updating an error is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353991/2991525

Comment: thank you Fabian but I've already seen that topic, not exactly the same issue and it's still not working.